# What is the best way to pass data into pycharm?

Tags: python, mysql, pycharm, plotly, bigdata

I uploaded data into MySQL and from there am using PyCharm and the plotly.offline library to pass in that data. My end goal is to create a scatter plot of the US with information on places of a certain latitude and longitude.

This is what I am trying to pass in:

```
checkin_data = pd.read_sql('select  bus.business_id,
         bus.latitude, bus.longitude,
         sum(chk.checkin_count ) as checkin_count
    from  yelp.business bus
    inner join  yelp.checkin chk  ON bus.business_id=chk.business_id
    group by  bus.business_id, bus.latitude, bus.longitude
    order by  bus.business_id
    limit  10;', con=connection)
```

I have limited the amount of rows to pass to just 10.

My question is how would I pass in all 10 rows to analyze? I am able to pass in the first one but I do not know how to pass in the rest so that I have a scatter plot with 10 points on the US.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is "analyze"?  The SELECT will return 10 rows of several columns each.

This will probably run faster:

```
select  bus.business_id, bus.latitude, bus.longitude, 
    (
        SELECT  sum(checkin_count)
            FROM  yelp.checkin
            WHERE  business_id = chk.business 
    ) AS checkin_count
    from  yelp.business bus
    order by  bus.business_id
    limit  10;
```

Comment: Thanks. By analyze I meant that using what I wrote above I need to pass in all 10 of them at a time into pyCharm.