# Indexing sql query

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing, bigdata

What would be the best way to index this:

```
select  bus.business_id, bus.latitude, bus.longitude, 
(
    SELECT  sum(checkin_count)
        FROM  yelp.checkin
        WHERE  business_id = chk.business 
) AS checkin_count
from  yelp.business bus
order by  bus.business_id
limit  10;
```

I am trying to index it this way:

```
 ALTER TABLE yelp.business ADD INDEX latitude_longitude_count_ndex (business_id, latitude, longitude);
```

but it is taking very long (ie I ran this overnight and it lost connection after about 2 hours).

I am running this in MySQL.

---

Side question, because this got me into indexing, is there a reason that this code:

```
select bus.business_id, bus.latitude, bus.longitude, sum(chk.checkin_count ) as checkin_count
from yelp.business bus 
inner join yelp.checkin chk 
    on bus.business_id=chk.business_id 
 group by bus.business_id, bus.latitude, bus.longitude
 order by bus.business_id
 limit 10;
```

is taking so long to query?
Even if I change the limit to just 1 it takes very long. I eventually stopped it after 4 minutes, but I have a feeling it shouldn't be taking that long.

Comment: I advised on a probably speedup [_here_].  If that is not sufficient, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.

Comment: Thanks. I don't think there was a hyperlink to here, but it seems to work now.

Comment: Oops -- [_in your other question_](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43750755/1766831)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set index for columns mentioned in `WHERE` or `JOIN` statements. So remove the index you've set and add one for `chk.business_id` or `bus.business_id` or both, and see what will be faster.